# Mysql Double Value Update Issue in some value like 1.86,1.36

Tags: mysql

I have table which contain field name stock (double value with unsigned check)
    Table Structure

```
id  stock
1   1.86
```

When i try to update some value like (1.86,1.36) its giving this error

```
Out of range value for column 'stock' at row 1
```

this my update query

```
Update sample set stock = stock - 1.86;
```

All other point value updating except this values..
I am using Mysql Version 5.6

Any Suggestion?

**EDIT**

i try like this

```
SELECT a.stock,a.`stock` - 1.36 FROM `sample` a;
```

Result is

```
stock  a.`stock` - 1.36
  1.36  -0.00
```

if change my query like this

```
SELECT a.stock,(ROUND(a.`stock`,2) - 1.36) FROM `sample` a;
```

Result is

```
 stock  (ROUND(a.`stock`,2) - 1.36)
  1.36  0.00
```

some how i managing now this problem. i hope its a mysql Bug.

Comment: what is the type of `stock` ?

Comment: @YCF_L it's written in the beginning of a question

Comment: It would appear the error is due to a rounding error, resulting in a negative value for the unsigned field. Not sure how to handle it better.

Comment: Try by changing datatype to VARCHAR

Comment: @TarangP The question is about mysql, not SQL Server. John: Would it be possible to change the column type to DECIMAL(9,2)?

Comment: I am not clear what this question is about - you will get this error (correctly) if the result of the update would take the stock negative.BTW double is not a good data type for stock since  FLOAT and DOUBLE types represent approximate numeric data values which I doubt stock ever is.

Comment: By doing this operation some negative values are generating in your db that's why this error

Comment: why its not working with double(10,2),is its mysql bug?

Comment: @P.Salmon my question is why only few values like (1.86,1.36),its not working with double(10,2).

Comment: It is not exactly a bug, but an unfixable problem of the data type. 1.36 cannot be represented exactly as a floating point number, it is represented by something like 1.359999999999 or 1.36000000001. If you subtract the latter from the former, the result is negative.

Answer (score 2):

Change the column type to **DOUBLE(5,2)** with **uncheck** UNSIGNED..

**Unsigned** type can be used to permit only **nonnegative** numbers in a column or when you need a larger upper numeric range for the column. For example, if an INT column is UNSIGNED, the size of the column's range is the same but its endpoints shift from -2147483648 and 2147483647 up to 0 and 4294967295.

Hope this will help.

Comment: if i did uncheck UNSIGNED,if the value is > 1.86 it will store as negative value.i want to alert users if they entering more the actual value so did this UNSIGNED check.

Comment: Coudn't understand. Do you want to store multiples of 1.86 ?

Comment: i mean to say > 1.86

Comment: Then you should add a trigger on update for reset  value>1.86 to what value you wish to store

Comment: my question is very simple why its not working with double(10,2) with some values if i try other values its working.BTW Thanks for ur reply

Comment: If the given value increases there is a chance to create non negative values in DB. Hence you checked unsigned db won't permit to store negative values